# JPanel FPS drops when moving mouse

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, frame-rate, mousemove

I'm making a small game in Java using an extension of Swing's `JPanel` as my drawing surface.

I draw everything inside panel's `paintComponent()`

The game runs smoothly until I start moving my mouse. When I do I get huge FPS drops, especially if i move it very fast, making the game unplayable.
That happens even when I stop drawing the mouse cursor.

Is this normal when drawing on `JComponent` objects?

P.S. I couldn't find any registered `MouseListener` or `MouseMotionListener` objects on any of my components.

---

**EDIT:**

### MCVE

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import javax.swing.*;

public class AnimationSlowDownOnMouse {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        JFrame mainWindow = new JFrame("dotShoot");
        mainWindow.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        mainWindow.setExtendedState(JFrame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH);

        final GamePanel gp = new GamePanel();
        gp.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(1920, 1080));
        mainWindow.add(gp);

        mainWindow.pack();
        gp.init();

        Thread gameThread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                final int maxTicksPerSecond = 100;
                final int optimalTimePerTick = 1000 / maxTicksPerSecond;

                final int maxFrameSkips = 5;

                long tickCount = 0L;
                float AvgIES = 0f;
                //int FPS = 0;          
                int DCPS = 0;
                int TPS = 0;
                long timeStarted = System.currentTimeMillis();
                long timeElapsed = 0L;

                int tickReset = 0;
                int drawCallsReset = 0;
                long timeReset = timeStarted;
                float interpolationReset = 0f;

                long nextLoop = timeStarted;
                int frameSkips = 0;

                float interpolation;

                while (true) {
                    synchronized (this) {
                        frameSkips = 0;

                        while (System.currentTimeMillis() > nextLoop && frameSkips < maxFrameSkips) {
                            gp.update(tickCount);
                            nextLoop += optimalTimePerTick;
                            tickCount++;
                            tickReset++;
                            frameSkips++;
                        }

                        interpolation = (float) (System.currentTimeMillis() + optimalTimePerTick - nextLoop) / (float) optimalTimePerTick;
                        gp.setInterpolation(interpolation);
                        gp.repaint();
                        interpolationReset += interpolation;
                        drawCallsReset++;
                        timeElapsed = System.currentTimeMillis() - timeStarted;

                        if (System.currentTimeMillis() - timeReset >= 1000) {
                            AvgIES = interpolationReset / (float) drawCallsReset;
                            interpolationReset = 0f;

                            TPS = tickReset;
                            tickReset = 0;

                            DCPS = drawCallsReset;
                            drawCallsReset = 0;

                            timeReset = System.currentTimeMillis();
                        }
                    }
                }

            }
        });
        gameThread.start();

        mainWindow.setVisible(true);

        gp.requestFocus();
    }

}

class GamePanel extends JPanel {

    /**
     *
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 3110478596996378903L;

    public GamePanel() {
        this.getInputMap().put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke("pressed A"), "pressed Key");
        this.getInputMap().put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke("released A"), "released Key");
        this.getInputMap().put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke("pressed D"), "pressed Key");
        this.getInputMap().put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke("released D"), "released Key");
        this.getInputMap().put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke("pressed W"), "pressed Key");
        this.getInputMap().put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke("released W"), "released Key");
        this.getInputMap().put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke("pressed S"), "pressed Key");
        this.getInputMap().put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke("released S"), "released Key");

        this.getActionMap().put("pressed Key", new AbstractAction() {
            private static final long serialVersionUID = 1296609706338138539L;

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                if (!pks.contains(arg0.getActionCommand())) {
                    pks += arg0.getActionCommand() + ", ";
                }
            }
        });

        this.getActionMap().put("released Key", new AbstractAction() {
            private static final long serialVersionUID = 4364732373538162119L;

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                pks = pks.replace(arg0.getActionCommand() + ", ", "");
            }
        });

        this.setBackground(new Color(0x6495ed));
    }

    public void init() {

    }

    private String pks = "";

    public void update(long currentTick) {

    }

    private float interpolation = 0;

    public void setInterpolation(float interpolation) {
        this.interpolation = interpolation;
    }

    private int frames = 0;
    private long timeForFPS = 0;
    private int ActualFPS = 0;

    public int getFPS() {
        return ActualFPS;
    }

    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);

        g.setColor(Color.black);
        g.drawString("FPS: " + ActualFPS, 0, 10);
        frames++;
        if (System.currentTimeMillis() - timeForFPS >= 1000) {
            ActualFPS = frames;
            frames = 0;
            timeForFPS = System.currentTimeMillis();
        }
    }
}
```

---

**EDIT 2:**

http://tinypic.com/r/9bkf4k/8
http://tinypic.com/r/345m24i/8

Comment: *"Is this normal when drawing on `JComponent` objects?"*  No, it sure isn't.

Comment: I was going to post some screenshots, but my reputation didn't allow me to.

Comment: I'm seeing 150-160 FPS while the mouse is not over the blue area, while 145-150 FPS when it is over the area.  Is that what you mean?  It does not seem very dramatic a drop to me..

Comment: What OS did you test it on?  I'm currently under win 8.1 x64 with fairly good specs. Also tested on a win 8 VM and a win 7 pc on my workplace.

Comment: @AndrewThompson These two files are from a fresh project, they built and run just fine for me. If there is an unclear part that i have to change, please tell me where and i will.

Comment: @LuxxMiner *"..the frames went literally from 390 to 4."*  It would have made more sense to express that in nice (small in bytes) **text** just like you did.  There is really no need for the screenshots.

Comment: @AndrewThompson Does the same happen when you rapidly move the cursor inside the game panel? Because that's when it becomes laggy for me. In more subtle movements the frame drop is indeed close to nonexistent

Comment: Nope.  Fast/slow mouse makes little difference here.  BTW - Is your video card using the latest drivers?  This is regularly a cause of rendering slow-downs..

Comment: Yes i have the latest drivers

Comment: On Mac OS X, I get results comparable to @AndrewThompson, who I usually see running Windows. There's no appreciable slowdown, but the `gameThread` pins one of my processors. How many do you have? Are you emulating?

Comment: `paintComponent` really isn't a good measuring point, as it may be called a number of times in quick succession and paint requests can be condensed down into fewer actual calls.  If you really want control over the painting system, start by using a `Canvas` and a `BufferStrategy` instead

Comment: @trashgod i have 8 physical cores on the dev machine, and a dual core setup on my workplace machine, i suppose it pins your processor because there is no limit on how many repaint calls are made.

Comment: @MadProgrammer Yes, that is why i have many draw calls and way less actuall redraws, that is expected. Using JPanel in place of a canvas is very common practice and still i couldn't find anyone facing a similar or the same problem with me. I'll give it a shot though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As with the other comments, there is no problem with FPS when I tried the code above here in my computer. I also tried it on my virtual machine having one processor only. Still there is no dramatic drop of the FPS when the mouse is moving fast. Although the processor always shows 100% usage. Have you tried this with other computers? I suspect, you too won't see the FPS problem in there. So maybe the issue lies in your computer and not on your program code.